# Reallocate Stat Points at SL90

Tags: dark-souls-2

Soul Level 90

> - VGR 16
> - END 21
> - VIT 15
> - ATN 6
> - STR 21
> - DEX 31
> - ADP 21
> - INT 7
> - FTH 5

I would like to reallocate my stats. I played Dark Souls with a pure Dex Build and for PvP (and PvE) I would like to try some miracles, hexes, ...
I looked up some builds however most of them were Sl150. Any input on how I could / should start building in the right direction. Would be a mix of Faith and Int for Hexes be worth it? Should I solely rely on Faith for the sunlight and lightning miracles?
This is all new to me so any input would be appreciated. I'm currently at Huntsman Copse.

Comment: What is the problem of a build for SL 150 ? You can just follow it, even if you can't complete it yet.

Comment: From what I can tell, you have quite a bit left in the game. Go and farm up some souls. sl150 isn't that hard to hit and you'll be able to use any of those builds as well as have most of the required items/spells used in those builds.

Comment: I would like to answer your question, could you let me know what your starting class is please?

Comment: @SimonM Oh I completly forgot to add that to my question. I started off as a swordsman.
slow_excellence & Shunwoo You are right of course I could just start leveling in that direction and I still have plenty of the game left. Almost 24 hours into it and I think it's only starting to begin.

Comment: @idkfa I have edited my answer using your class's base stats.

Comment: As for my question put on hold. I don't really know how to edit my question accordingly as there is no definitive answer to my question. It lies within the nature of the game and its endless possibilities that I will receive more of suggestions and guidelines that the one true answer. However I'm well aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are at the ideal area to start using hexes, you may or may not have met with [Felkin](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Felkin+the+Outcast), the hooded man sitting on a chair just before the first bonfire. He specialises in hexes. I would put at the very least 20 in both Faith and Intelligence, this is because if you have 20 or more faith + intelligence, not only will he trade you some amazing hexes, he will also give you his set ([Hexer Set](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Hexer+Set)) and the [Sunset Staff](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Sunset+Staff). The staff is great, arguably one of the best. My personal favourite is the [Black Witch's Staff](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Black+Witch%27s+Staff); very high damage and can be used as both a talisman and catalyst.

In regards to stat distribution, I am a lover of maximising my damage first. For this reason I would go for this:

> - VGR - 16
> - END - 15
> - VIT - 4 (Default)
> - ATN - 16
> - STR - 9 (Default)
> - DEX - 16 (Default)
> - ADP - 6 (Default)
> - INT - 30
> - FTH - 30

For your end game, it depends on whether you want to integrate any kind of melee and what spells you wish to cast. Many of the very strong spells require very high stats, especially intelligence focused ones, if you want to stick to hexes, they do not require very high stats. For example, the spell [Great Resonant Soul](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Great+Resonant+Soul) is ridiculously strong but only requires 13 int and 26 faith. The Black Witch's Staff is capable of doing a decent amount of damage because of the very high scaling when using it in melee, so you may decide to be a completely dedicated caster and use the staff in melee when you must.

Your final stat distribution at SL150 may look something like this:

> - VGR - 30
> - END - 15
> - VIT - 4 (Default)
> - ATN - 30
> - STR - 9 (Default)
> - DEX - 16 (Default)
> - ADP - 18
> - INT - 40
> - FTH - 40

Keep in mind that there are plenty of suggested builds and stat distribution guides out there, this is just my own personal one. You may wish to search for more and see what suits you best.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the kind of guidance I seeked. I think I will go with your build and see where it takes from there. I assume the Black Witch's Staff kann be used as an meele weapon as well then. I already met Felkin but he wanted to be left alone. I'll report back how I liked it.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question. Anyone can find SL150 builds anywhere on the net. Also, the OP has commented above they started as a Swordsman, so if you feel so inclined you can edit your stats accordingly.

Comment: @idkfa Glad to help. The staff can be used in melee using R2 or whatever your strong attack button is. It does reasonably high damage because of the huge scaling it gets from faith and int.

Comment: @SimonM I already went with you first suggestion and pumped VIT too. However I'm not to disappointed with the extra equipload if wearing more heavy armor.
But I have 2 questions concerning your suggested items. I can't cast Great Resonant Soul with the Sun Setstaff. Do I have to infuse it first? And the second question is also about the GRS, it doesn't really do a ton of damage. I checked some youtube footage where it went to 1k and above. I'm stuck at 300-400, maybe 450 if i'm lucky. Currently at 32/32 INT FTH.

Comment: @idkfa Dark magic got really badly nerfed recently, due to the insane amount of damage you could pull off with it. Also I believe that GRS requires a Chime rather than a Staff as a catalyst. Try the Idol's Chime or (if you have it) Caitha's Chime. Both have good scaling in Dark Damage.

Comment: @idkfa I apolagise for not responding to you sooner. I was unaware of the recent nerfs to dark magic, however it may not be useless. I'm not sure if Dark Orb got nerfed but even so, the amount of charges you get and the damage it did made it great for clearing enemies in PVE. Also you do need a chime to cast dark magic, you can buy a good one from Felkin, but as I mentioned in my answer; you can use the Black Witch's Staff as a chime and a catalyst, but unfortunately you only get it quite late in the game.